# Socket.io Save dynamic rooms and keep the client connected Node JS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im fairly new to socket.io.
I went through their documentation page and some posts here on SO, but I'm stuck with my approach. I'm planning for a quiz application where an admin can create dynamic rooms for each topic and users can join. The admin will post the question and users get 10 secs to answer before the PDA locks the answer tab. The admin will post the answer later through admin CP.

Now my questions.
1. Can we create dynamic rooms from admin panel and store the room name in database so that the clients can join the same room later?
2. How do i keep the clients connected until the answers are posted sometime later? without the clients getting disconnected.   // something like whatsapp group
3. Even if the clients get disconnected, can i join the clients with the room meta data stored in the DB?
4. If 10 clients answer my question, can the server parse their data and store it with their ID in the DB?

Appreciate any help on this. I do not have an idea on how to go about this. I followed many tutorials, but failed to achieve what I need. Sorry for the lengthy post, but any leads will definitely help me
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Can we create dynamic rooms from admin panel and store the room name in database so that the clients can join the same room later?

Yes, you can.

> 2. How do i keep the clients connected until the answers are posted sometime later? without the clients getting disconnected. // something
>      like whatsapp group

Socket.io automatically keeps the connection alive as long as the originating page is alive in the browser.  If the connection is lost, it will reconnect.  If the user goes to another page that does not have socket.io code in it, then there will be no connection.  The connection is established in a given page when the client connects via socket.io.  You can have all your pages connect via socket.io if you always want to have a connection as long as the user is on your site.

> 3. Even if the clients get disconnected, can i join the clients with the room meta data stored in the DB?

If the client is no longer connected to your site, then there's nothing for you to do as you don't have any ability to communicate with that user.  Connections are a client-driven thing.  The client must establish a connection to your server.  When the client reconnects, you can look up their state in the database to reconnect to certain rooms or look up any messages they may have missed while they were disconnected and send those to the newly reconnected client.  But, this is up to you to store that info and know how to query it to get the right info to send a newly connected client.

> 4. If 10 clients answer my question, can the server parse their data and store it with their ID in the DB?

Yes, you can write code to do that.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00  . Can I have some example code for dynamic sockets as a lead? I searched but could not find suitable code for my requirement. Any tutorials would also do. Thanks.

Comment: @Pavan - I'm not sure I know what you mean by "dynamic sockets".

Comment: I mean, whenever the server creates a new room on a specific topic, say, geography or animals. A new socket or room should be created for the users to listen to and should be stored in the DB. My rest API would display all the room IDs in the app so that users can click and join the room and start emitting events.

Comment: @Pavan - There is no specific step to "create" a socket.io room.  So, the list of rooms available would just be something you would keep in your own app and offer those to your users (nothing to do with socket.io).  Then, if anyone selects to join one of those rooms, you just use socket.io's `.join()` and it automatically creates the chat room when the first user joins it.

Comment: I have an admin who needs to setup the questions that need to be delivered to the users. So, How do I make sure that the admin joins first and creates the room and rest of the users join the same room from the app? Thanks

Comment: @Pavan - The list of rooms you want to offer needs to be something you keep track of in your own app, probably something you store in a database.  This is an app-specific thing, nothing to do with socket.io.  When a user then wants to join that room, then you use socket.io to connect them to that room name.

Comment: Also, @jjfriend00 Can a browser client connect to 2 rooms at once? 
ex : socket.join(room1) & socket.join(room2) . Im planning to divide the screen into 2, so the first half of the screen should connect to room 1 and post questions for a set of users and room 2 should do it for the other. Is it feasible? Thanks

Comment: @Pavan -  Yes, a socket can belong to as many rooms as desired.  I've answered a bunch of your questions, but this isn't really how stack overflow is designed to work.  Comments shouldn't be used to continue to ask more questions after the original question is done.